# Using PowerShell to convert JSON file into .CSV file?

Tags: json, powershell, azure-powershell

How can I format the Input.CSV which contains JSON into Output .CSV which will show the column like:

```
Date (Local Timezone, not UTC), IP Address, User, Record Type, Activity, Item
```

See the sample Input.csv in the below:

```
RecordId,CreationDate,RecordType,Operation,UserId,AuditData,AssociatedAdminUnits,AssociatedAdminUnitsNames
GUID,1/24/2023 12:39:18 AM,20,ViewReport,User.name@MyDomain.com,"{
    ""Id"": ""GUID"",
    ""RecordType"": 20,
    ""CreationTime"": ""2023-01-24T00:39:18"",
    ""Operation"": ""ViewReport"",
    ""OrganizationId"": ""GUID"",
    ""UserType"": 0,
    ""UserKey"": ""123"",
    ""Workload"": ""PowerBI"",
    ""UserId"": ""User.name@MyDomain.com"",
    ""ClientIP"": ""123.11.22.33"",
    ""Activity"": ""ViewReport"",
    ""ItemName"": ""Important Report"",
    ""WorkSpaceName"": ""banking Confidential Data"",
    ""DatasetName"": ""Corporate Finance"",
    ""ReportName"": ""Corporate Finance"",
    ""CapacityId"": ""GUID"",
    ""CapacityName"": ""Shared On Premium - Reserved"",
    ""WorkspaceId"": ""GUID"",
    ""ObjectId"": ""Corporate Finance"",
    ""DatasetId"": ""GUID"",
    ""ReportId"": ""GUID"",
    ""ArtifactId"": ""GUID"",
    ""ArtifactName"": ""Corporate Finance"",
    ""IsSuccess"": true,
    ""ReportType"": ""PowerBIReport"",
    ""RequestId"": ""GUID"",
    ""ActivityId"": ""GUID"",
    ""DistributionMethod"": ""Shared"",
    ""ConsumptionMethod"": ""Power BI Web"",
    ""ArtifactKind"": ""Report""
}",,
```

The big challenge here is to convert the Date column from UTC into the local timezone.

```
#some json data...
$jsonData = Import-CSV -path C:\Input.CSV


#convert JSON to PowerShell
$psData = $jsonData | ConvertFrom-Json

# then exporting...
$psData | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\psData.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.ToLocalTime()` method from `datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tolocaltime) for this. In PowerShell 7+ `ConvertFrom-Json` would already convert the `CreationTime` key in your Json into a `datetime` instance thus the casting of `[datetime]` wouldn't be needed but for compatibility with both versions you should leave it as is.

```
Import-Csv C:\Input.CSV | ForEach-Object AuditData |
    ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date       = ([datetime] $_.CreationTime).ToLocalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
            IpAddress  = $_.ClientIp
            User       = $_.UserId
            RecordType = $_.RecordType
            Activity   = $_.Activity
            Item       = $_.ItemName
        }
    } | Export-Csv c:\temp\psData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: many thanks once again man, yes this is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below :

```
$x = Import-CSV -path "C:\Users\Downloads\emooo.csv"
$y=$x.AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
$o = [DateTimeOffset]::Parse($y.CreationTime)
$datetime = $o.UtcDateTime
$local = [TimeZoneInfo]::Local
$localtime = [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc($datetime, $local)
$y.CreationTime = $localtime 
$z=$x | Select-Object -Property RecordId,CreationDate, RecordType, Operation, UserId
foreach ($emo in $y.PSObject.Properties) {
$z | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $emo.Name -Value $emo.Value -Force
}
$z | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Downloads\vammo.csv"
```

[image]

Output :

[image]

[image]

Now(Just to check):

```
$z
```

[image]